# Azure DevOps Extension Placeholders

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I want to be able to use a place holder in the extension code that takes its actual value from the extension manifest upon packaging (or build), such as the version.

So for example in the `vss-extension.json` there's a `version` property set to `1.2.3`, so in the build task code inside that extension I want to be able to use something like that:

```
// index.ts
var agentId = "myext-azurepipelines-${extension.version}";
```

that would translate to:

```
// index.ts
var agentId = "myext-azurepipelines-1.2.3";
```

when packaging or building, but without changing the original file (a template of a sort).

Is something like this available?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your requirement is not able to achieve currently. You have to modify the original file.

Comment: Is my reply helpful?